# Check if data is exist in SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I use this function to get specific data from SQlite:

```
SearchRes getSresultByName(String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_WIKIRES, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_SNAME, KEY_SJSON }, KEY_SNAME + "=?",
            new String[] { name }, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    SearchRes searchres = new SearchRes(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));

    return searchres;
}
```

And it works just fine, I need to create similar function to test if value is exist in the table, so I tried this:

```
boolean checkIfExist(String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_WIKIRES, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_SNAME, KEY_SJSON }, KEY_SNAME + "=?",
            new String[] { name }, null, null, null, null);


    if (cursor == null)
        return false;

    else
        return true;

}
```

But I always get TRUE. Can you help me figure out what is the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18868712/android-sqlite-search-by-name#18868911

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should not be checking if cursor is null you should be checking if anything exists in the cursor

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
    return true
}else{
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try `Cursor` [getCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getCount%28%29) to check the number of rows in the result of the query.. Following is the sample code:

```
boolean checkIfExist(String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_WIKIRES, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_SNAME, KEY_SJSON }, KEY_SNAME + "=?",
            new String[] { name }, null, null, null, null);


    if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
        return true;

    else
        return false;

}
```

answer by @tyczj is also good..

Comment: doing this is redundant because if there is a count > 0 then you have to call `movetoFirst()` anyway or else you will get an out of bounds error

Comment: agree.. but the purpose of the method is not to read data but to check if data exists.. and as I mentioned in my answer.. both approaches are good..

Comment: As explained by [Doug Currie](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8618629/342618), getCount() is potentially a very expensive operation. Therefore I'd suggest it be avoided unless you need to get the total count.

Comment: But, I checked for null in Cursor, but there were exceptions shown in catch block when cursor count is 0, but,  after applying the above method now fine, thanks for the approach.